# My volume icon disappeared after I updated to Yosemite.

Tags: macbook-pro, icon, macos

My volume icon disappeared after I updated to OS X Yosemite 10.10.  I still have sound.  resetting the PRAM didn't work. 
I have refurbished 2012 Macbook Air

Answer (score 42):

Go to System Preferences then Sound, then put a check on "Show volume in menu bar".

[image]

Answer (score 27):

If you're using Bartender, check that it's not set to completely hide the volume icon.

You would think if you had this answer's problem you wouldn't need this answer, but then you wouldn't be thinking of me -_-

Comment: True story: This had this problem again, I googled it, and I found this.

Comment: Yeah, me too.  Installed bartender on a new Mac today and for some reason it defaults to hiding the volume icon completely.

Comment: I don't know when I set Volume to be completely hidden in BarTender :(

Comment: @Tatsh looks like a default setting, I'm having the same issue

Comment: Mine certainly was not set to hide it. I had the machine crash (yeah... I know... a Mac crashed. Hasn't happened in months! ;) ). And on reboot - no volume icon. This answer made me check and... it was set to be hidden. Nothing else was out of place - just the sound icon.

Answer (score 3):

Open System Preferences, click on **Sound** (in the second section, all the way to the right), then make sure *Show volume in menu bar* is checked.